# JMeter: How to keep connection open and read data from it?

Tags: jmeter

I want to test one feature, and I need open connection to send some JSONs in it (from server to JMeter) from time to time, but I'm new to JMeter and can't get how to do it.

So, two steps I need help with:

1. How to keep connection open?
2. How to get data from JSON and trigger some action? (just couple of requests in my case)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you are planning to SOAP/REST with JMeter, it can be done. However your question does not seem to be clear! 'from server to JMeter'?

Comment: @vIns in this case, JMeter is like client device, waiting for some kind of push notifications. Device (JMeter in this case) have to open connection and wait for notifications from server. And yes, this is REST.

Comment: If it will help to understand what I mean, in real client app there's `DataInputStream` from `Socket`, and thread, reading data from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, seems like there's no standart solution for this, but you can create your own implementation of [TCPSampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/tcp/sampler/TCPSampler.html) or override TCPClientImpl and use it in [TCPClient classname](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#TCP_Sampler)